# .htaccess file for Uploading a Zend Framework Project on 1and1

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, web-hosting

The problem I have is that I am trying to put a Zend Framework web application online and while it works perfectly on my localhost, it has a lot of errors online. I know that there are certain things required for a Zend website to work.

- I need the document root to be serwano.com/staging/fbr
- I need php5
- I need mod rewrite on

I need the document root to be serwano.com/staging/fbr. 
I have a testing website with the following folder set up:

```
/webroot(serwano.com)      
    /staging  
       /other test site  
       /other test site  
       /fbr  
           /application  
           /library  
           /public
```

I need help determining what the appropriate .htaccess file would be so that my Zend Web App will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can figure the webroot for a domain to point to any folder insider your FTP upload directory, thus you can do

```
+ userhome
|- serwano.com
|-- staging
|-- test
|-- production
```

Then go to your 1&1 control panel and create three subdomains for serwano.com. There should be an option to point each subdomain's webroot to the appropriate folder, e.g.

```
staging.serwano.com // point it to the staging folder
test.serwano.com    // point it to the test folder
www.serwano.com     // point it to the production folder
```

Whether you can use .htaccess and mod_rewrite depends on how your webhosting package is configured. Contact 1&1 *(prepare for pain)* to find out if that is possible. If it is not possible, Google has a number of results for [Zend Framework without .htaccess](http://www.google.de/search?q=zend+framework+without+htaccess). You do not need `mod_rewrite`, nor `.htaccess`. This is just recommended.